# How to listen for DOM updates in a react.js component?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to figure out why a react.js component is not updating when I call this.setState() from it. I would like to try to listen for all DOM updates as a way of debugging this. Is this possible?

```
var ChangingProgressBar = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
     return {'percentage': 0, 
            'mood':'progress-bar-info'}
  },
  componentWillMount: function(){
    self = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
      self.setState({'mood', 'progress-bar-danger'});
    }, 2000);
  },
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div className='progress-bar {this.state.mood}'
       role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='{this.state.percentage}'
       aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100'
       style="{{width: this.state.percentage + '%'}}">
         {this.state.percentage}%
      </div>
    )
  })
})
```

Comment: Post some code please

Comment: Are you overriding `shouldComponentUpdate`?

Comment: `style="width: {this.state.percentage}%"` needs to be `style={{width: this.state.percentage + '%'}}`

Comment: `aria-valuenow='{this.state.percentage}'` needs to be `aria-valuenow={this.state.percentage}`

Comment: It also turns out that I need `{this.state.mood}` in a separate className.
`<div className='progress-bar' className={this.state.mood}`

Comment: I doubt that works? I'd write it as `className={'progress-bar ' + this.state.mood}`

Comment: looks fine in [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wno7w4ww/)

Answer (score 0):

```
self.setState({'mood', 'progress-bar-danger'});
```

should be

```
self.setState({'mood': 'progress-bar-danger'});
```